# GPS Geolocation app doesn't work in Phonegap for Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I'm creating an app which gets user's position. The apps works correctly using 3G, the issue comes when i disabled 3G and wanna run app using only the GPS, the app it even't start.

The code i have:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
}

function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660042/phonegap-geolocalisation-application-crashes?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Geolocation doesn't mean that you're going to be using the GPS. By default, you'll be using the network location.You have to enable high accuracy!

Comment: This is done by adding Position.FINE to the permissions in the manifest, per my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure your permissions int he manifest includes Position.FINE so that your application will be allowed to use the gps reciever.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Android Manifest and check you have permissions to do it.